# Vue.js: How to rerun your code whenever you change slides in your vue carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am very new to vue.js and fumbling my way though it, forgive me if my terms are incorrect. I am creating a touchscreen application that needs to be ADA compliant (only the bottom part of the screen is accessible, so i have to use buttons for interaction).

I have a parent component with a carousel creating an array of slides, pulling data from my child component.

parent component HTML

```
<carousel :navigateTo="selectedListIndex" @pageChange="OnPageChange">
  <slide v-for="(member, index) in selectedList" :key="index">
     <MemberBioPage :member="member"/>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

parent component SCRIPT:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentPage: 0
    }
  },
  components: {
    MemberBioPage,
    Carousel,
    Slide
  },
  computed: {
    selectedList () {
      return this.$store.state.selectedList
    },
    selectedListIndex () {
      return this.$store.state.selectedListIndex
    }
  },
  methods: {
    OnPageChange (newPageIndex) {
      console.log(newPageIndex)
      this.currentPage = newPageIndex
    }
  }
}
```

within my child component, i have bio copy being pulled from my data and arrow buttons that allow you to scroll the text. There is an outer container and an inner container to allow the scrolling and based on the height that the content takes up in the container will determine when the arrows disable or not.

child component HTML:

```
<div class="member-bio-page">
  <div class="bio">
    <div class="portrait-image">
       <img :src="member.imgSrc" />
    </div>
    <div class="bio-container">
      <div class="inner-scroll" v-bind:style="{top: scrollVar + 'px'}">
         <h1>{{ member.name }}</h1>
         <div class="description-container">
            <div class="para">
              <p v-html="member.shortBio"></p>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="scroll-buttons">
       <div>
       <!-- set the class of active is the scroll variable is less than 0-->
         <img class="btn-scroll" v-bind:class="{ 'active': scrollVar < 0 }" @click="scrollUp" src="@/assets/arrow-up.png">
       </div>
       <div>
         <!-- set the class of active is the scroll variable is greater than the height of the scrollable inner container-->
         <img class="btn-scroll" v-bind:class="{ 'active': scrollVar > newHeight }" @click="scrollDown" src="@/assets/arrow-down.png">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

child component SCRIPT:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'member', 'currentPage'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      scrollVar: 0,
      outerHeight: 0,
      innerHeight: 0,
      newHeight: -10
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.outerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('bio-container')[0].clientHeight
    this.innerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('inner-scroll')[0].clientHeight
    this.newHeight = this.outerHeight - this.innerHeight
    return this.newHeight
  },
  methods: {
    scrollUp () {
      console.log(this.scrollVar)
      this.scrollVar += 40
    },
    scrollDown () {
      console.log(this.scrollVar)
      this.scrollVar -= 40
    },
    showVideo () {
      this.$emit('showContent')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am able to get the height of the first bio i look at, but on page change it keeps that set height. I basically want the code in mounted to be able to rerun based on the index of the slide i am on. I need 'newHeight' to update on each page change. I tried grabbing the 'currentPage' from my parent component using props, but it pulls undefined.

here is all a snippet from my data to show you what data i currently have:

```
{
  index: 12,
  name: 'Name of Person',
  carouselImage: require('@/assets/carousel-images/image.jpg'),
  imgSrc: require('@/assets/bio-page-image-placeholder.jpg'),
  shortBio: '<p>a bunch of text being pulled</p>',
  pin: require('@/assets/image-of-pin.png')
}
```

this is also my store just in case

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foundersList: founders,
    chairmanList: chairmans,
    selectedList: founders,
    selectedListIndex: -1
  },
  mutations: {
    setSelectedState (state, list) {
      state.selectedList = list
    },
    setSelectedListIndex (state, idx) {
      state.selectedListIndex = idx
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this is a good start. Here's a few things I would try:

1. Move the code you currently have in `mounted` to a new method called `calculateHeight` or something similar.
2. Call the method from your `scrollUp` and `scrollDown` methods.

So your final code would look something like this:

```
export default {
  props: [
    'member', 'currentPage'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      scrollVar: 0,
      outerHeight: 0,
      innerHeight: 0,
      newHeight: -10
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.calculateHeight();
  },
  methods: {
    calculateHeight() {
      this.outerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('bio-container')[0].clientHeight
      this.innerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('inner-scroll')[0].clientHeight
      this.newHeight = this.outerHeight - this.innerHeight
    },
    scrollUp () {
      console.log(this.scrollVar)
      this.scrollVar += 40
      this.calculateHeight()
    },
    scrollDown () {
      console.log(this.scrollVar)
      this.scrollVar -= 40
      this.calculateHeight()
    },
    showVideo () {
      this.$emit('showContent')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so once it has calculated the height, i need it to disable the arrow button if it is at the top of the container and disable the bottom arrow when it is at the bottom of the container. I currently do that with the binded style 'active'. With the calculateHeight being added to the the button function itself, will i be able to do that? Sorry, i realize i did not explain that in my question

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't change anything with you you disable and enable buttons.